# Ruby on Rails, creating CMS with content types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, content-management-system, content-type, rails-models

I'm learning RoR nowadays and came up with an idea of creating a very simple content management system. I would like to allow users to create structure of content by adding fields, then the app would create pages to add new items and list all items of given type. I've seen something similar in Drupal where users can define their own content type.

I wonder how to do it:

1.Using relational DB: Should I store content type as (for example) serialized hash of "id => type_of_field" and execute SQL to create db schema in controller after getting it from user? Is there any better way to achieve this? Can it cause problems with future db migrations?

2.How to create views, controllers and routes? Should there be only one controller handling routes to content types by itself without using routes.rb and creating views dynamically from partials? Is there more elegant way to do this?
Thanks for all clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can fix the layout for basic simple CMS.
like left_side_bar,can_left_side_bar,right_side_bar,top_nav,sub_nav,footer,header,body DB field and checks for displaying content.so basically cut down pages and map to db field,

Checkout various CMS available and go through their architecture it will help you to understand in terms of architecture wise.

List of CMS
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems